# Log Unsub Event Update HaasOptedOut field in Sales cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, landing-page, unsubscribe

I'm using "Log A Unsub Event" using ampsript in a cloud page to unsubscribe the subscriber in marketing cloud, also my Marketing cloud instance is a multi org enbled org.

When I'm unsubscribing the user using the "Log A Unsub Event" in ampscript, it also updates the "EmailOptOut" field in Sales cloud and updates it to true and we do not want this becuase we have multiple BU's connected to same Sales cloud environment.

I also tried updating the record back to false for "EmailOptOut" using "UpdateSalesforceSingleObject" for this field, but it did not work.

How can we prevent the "EmailOptOut" field update when we fire "Log A Unsub Event" using ampsript or re-update the "EmailOptOut" back to false when it is once updated  by ""Log A Unsub Event" using ampsript.

Below mentioned is the code :-

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
</script>
%%[

/* SET @emailAddress = requestparameter("Email") 
set @SubKey= requestparameter("SubKey")*/
set @SubKey= "00QsssasasEffffgea"
set @jid= requestparameter("jobid")
set @listid= requestparameter("listid")

 SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
 SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

 SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
 SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
 SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @SubKey)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

 SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
 SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
 SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

 SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
 SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
 SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

/*
 SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
 SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
 SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
 AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
*/

/* You must set ClientID when working with On Your Behalf accounts*/
var @lue_oyb 
set @lue_oyb = CreateObject('ClientID') 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_oyb, 'ID','232322323')
SetObjectProperty(@lue, 'Client', @lue_oyb)
    
    SET @rowset = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'HasOptedOutOfEmail', 'Id', '=', '00QsssasasEffffgea')
    set @numberOfRows = RowCount(RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Email', 'Id', '=', '00QsssasasEffffgea'))
    set @HasOptedOutOfEmailValue = Field(Row(@rowset, 1), "HasOptedOutOfEmail")

 SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

 SET @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
 SET @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
 SET @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")
        
        
      SET @initialValue = Substring(@SubKey,1,3)
      SET @DEName = AttributeValue("_DataSourceName")
      
      SET @flag = "False"
      If @HasOptedOutOfEmailValue =='true' THEN
        SET @flag = 'true'
      ELSEIf @HasOptedOutOfEmailValue =='false' THEN
        SET @flag = 'false'
      ENDIF
    
    SET @PersonContactID = ""
    SET @updateRecord =0

    IF @initialValue == "003" THEN
      set @AID = LookupRows("Accounts","PersonContactID",@SubKey)
      set @row = row(@AID, 1) 
      set @PersonContactID = field(@row,"Id")
     
    ENDIF
    
  
  IF @initialValue == "003" THEN
   SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account",@PersonContactID,"MTI_Email_Opt_Out__c",1)
   
   
  
  ELSEIF @initialValue == "00Q" THEN
    SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead",@SubKey,"MTI_Email_Opt_Out__c",1)
    
    ENDIF
    
    UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead",'00QsssasasEffffgea',"HasOptedOutOfEmail",@flag)
    
    SET @rowset1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'HasOptedOutOfEmail', 'Id', '=', '00QsssasasEffffgea')
    set @numberOfRows1 = RowCount(RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Email', 'Id', '=', '00QsssasasEffffgea'))
    set @HasOptedOutOfEmailValue1 = Field(Row(@rowset1, 1), "HasOptedOutOfEmail")
    
]%%
<script runat="server">
}catch(e){
 Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

Comment: check all comments and answers here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307080/how-can-i-reactivate-users-that-have-been-unsubscribed-using-logunsubevent-in/307203#307203

Comment: @JonasLamberty , so how to updated the "EmailOptOutField" back to false using ampscript in SF back when the script to Unsub runs asynchronusly.

Comment: Option 1, call ampscript in a contentblock from within an SSJS script. in AMPscript, use upsertSingleSalesforceObject. This does not scale, as you won't be able to retrieve more than 2500 records (=unsubscriptions) at a time. check: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241809/ssjs-to-call-content-block-with-ampscript ; option 2, use bulk api. Much more work but will scale and the general solution pattern is pretty useful. check: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286883/account-activity-or-object-activity-in-journey-builder-has-limits-to-update-like/286998#286998